# How can I listen to Slack channels that the bot is added to? Which Oauth do I require?

Tags: python, oauth, slack, slack-api

Currently it seems that I am only listening to public channels when using

```
@app.event('message')
```

https://api.slack.com/scopes/groups:read

Is this the Oauth I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of conversation you want to listen to,

there are different scopes as mentioned below:

- **Public Channels**   : `channels:read`
- **Private Channels**  : `groups:read`
- **Multi-Person DMs** : `mpim:read`
- **Direct Messages**  : `im:read`

Comment: thank you very much, this was resolved by above

Comment: Can you mark the answer as 'Accepted' so that it will help others as well ?